# Vertical alignment of multiline legend entries

Tags: r, plot

As the following example shows, symbols and labels are not correctly aligned by the R function `legend()` for mutiline labels including math expressions, and playing with the legend parameter `adj` apparently does not help:

```
plot(0, 0, type = "n")

legend("topleft", c(expression(paste(x[i], "bla bla\n... bla, bla")), "y"), 
       col = 1, lty = 1:2)
legend("topright", c(expression(paste(x[i], "bla bla\n... bla, bla")), "y"), 
       col = 2, lty = 1:2, adj = c(0, 2))
```

[image: wrong legend display]

Is it possible to make the symbols (the horizontal lines on the left) aligned with the *first* line of each label text?

**Edit:** In variation of the idea for a workaround by [@nir-graham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180859/11304107), I could simulate what I wanted with multiple calls to `legend()` This is an ugly crutch, though, and suggestions for an actual solution are still welcome:

```
plot(0, 0, type = "n")
legend("topleft", c(expression(x[i]), "... bla, bla", "y"), col=c(1,"white",1), lty=c(1,NA,2))
legend("topleft", c("    bla, bla"), col=NA, lty=1, bty="n")
```

[image: legend workaround]

Answer (score 1):

There may be, but I doubt theres an elegant way to do this with base plotting;
probably manual placement like

```
plot(0, 0, type = "n")
legend("topleft", c(expression(x[i]),
                      expression("y")), 
       col = 1, lty = 1:2,text.width = .5,y.intersp=3)
text(x = -.5,y=,.55,labels="bla bla\n... bla, bla\nbla bla")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For better alignment, it is preferable to call `legend()` multiple times instead of using `text()`. I have edited my question to include this workaround.